# How to enlarge a label as the container is enlarged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a custom UserControl in WPF, which has a stack panel docked to the top to replace the title bar functionality.

The left part of the stack panel has a label, which contains a textblock for text wrapping in cases where the label would contain a long string.

My problem arises when dragging the control.  I would naturally like the label's text to display more and more as the window is dragged.

I would like the label to enlarge as the window is enlarged, but I am not sure how to approach this.

This is the code I've written to achieve the titlebar in the screenshots:

```
<Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="titleBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="28" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="AliceBlue">
                <Button x:Name="btnClose" Margin="0,0,5,0" Click="btnClose_Click">                  
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnRunQuery" ToolTip="Run Query">                   
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnFilter" ToolTip="Toggle Filter" Click="btnFilter_Click">                    
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnAttributes">      
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnAll" Click="btnAll_Click">ALL</Button>
                <Label Name="lblTableName" FontSize="14" MaxWidth="150">
                    <TextBlock Name="tbTableName" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**EDIT:** I'd also like to add that when the user control is rendered, I do not want the label's width to be more than 150. Hence the `MaxWidth="150"` property.  However, I want the label to grow as the window is enlarged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Grid instead of StackPanel.
the last Column which contains the label should have Width="Auto". you can add another column before that (I mean to the right side of the label column), with Width="*" in order to fill the empty area between label and buttons when window is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor the label to the edges. You should see the anchoring symbol to the 4 sides when you click the label. When anchored the 4 symbols will be black.